# Get Top 11 rows with Non Zeros column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame that looks like the following. It has 11 column that contains only zeros and ones, along with a column with some values and the last column is an identifier. I am facing a problem with data frame manipulation.

I have a situation where I need to select the top 11 rows based on the 'values' column. (Loose Constraint)

But the tricky part is I have to select the rows in such a way that I do not get any zero columns in those eleven rows. (Hard Constraint).

So I need to select to top 11 rows based on values and make sure all columns are non-zero. At least one value in each column should be 1.

I am looking for some generic solution as the values in the Value column will change but my goal of selecting 11 rows based on value and making sure a non-zero column is a must.

Any ideas?

```
a    b  c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k      values ID
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.193744   1
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.193744   2
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.193744   3
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.193744   4
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.193744   5
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.193744   6
0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.193744   7
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.633150   8
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.633150   9
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.633150  10
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.633150  11
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.633150  12
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  13
0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  14
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  15
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  16
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  17
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.033640  18
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.033640  19
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.033640  20
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.033640  21
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  22
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  23
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  24
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.033640  25
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -0.279495 26
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -3.013531 27
1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 -3.013531 28
```

Comment: So you want to find the highest value where a = 1, highest for b = 1, ....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom function - first sorting `values`, then select first 11 columns by
[`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), convert floats to boolean `True` and `False`s by [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html), so possible test each N chunks if at least one `1` by [`DataFrame.rolling`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rolling.html) with `any`, so get rows shifted by `N` filled by `NaN`s, is necessary repalce them by `0`, convert to boolean, spo possible test if all rows has `1` by  [`DataFrame.all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html).

Last get index of first `True`, but if all `False`s it return `0` in [`Series.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.idxmax.html), so added `if-else` statement.

Last filter top11 by indexing:

```
def top_val_with_at_least_one_1(df, N):
    df = df.sort_values('values', ascending=False, ignore_index=True, kind='mergesort')

    m = (df.iloc[:, :11]
           .astype(bool)
           .rolling(N)
           .apply(lambda x: x.any())
           .fillna(0)
           .astype(bool)
           .all(axis=1))
    
    if m.any():
        idx = m.idxmax()
        return df.loc[idx-N+1:idx]
    else:
        return pd.DataFrame()


print (top_val_with_at_least_one_1(df, 11))
      a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j    k    values  ID
5   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.193744   6
6   0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.193744   7
7   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.633150   8
8   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.633150   9
9   0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.633150  10
10  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.633150  11
11  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.633150  12
12  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.033640  13
13  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.033640  14
14  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.033640  15
15  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  1.0  0.0  0.0  0.033640  16
```

Comment: it gets top 11 rows with max values but column a and b are all zeroes.  We need to find top rows but the column it should include should not zero

Comment: I tried changing to all then it give me empty dataframe with column headers. 
Possibly because it tried to get top 11 based on values.

Comment: I want to get all column 11 of them non-zero.  At least one element should be 1 in all columns.
In your above solution col a  and b are zero columns

Comment: Yes, with your solution it selects rows in such a way that in final outcome. Column a and b are completely zero. We need to get rows in such a way that at least 1 element in each column is 1 else can all be zero based on top values. 
So if top values return rows where 1 column is completely zero. we can swap it with another one but the non zero column constraint is must

Comment: @Waqarulislam - Answer was edited.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
def get_desired_subset(top_rows):
    for i in range(len(df)):
        df_subset = df.loc[i:i+top_rows-1].reset_index(drop=True)
        if (df_subset>0).any().all():
            return df_subset

    print('No such subset found that satisfies all constraints.')
    return pd.DataFrame()

top_rows = 3
df = df[(df>0).any(axis=1)].sort_values(subset=['values'], ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
if len(df)>= top_rows:
    desired_df = get_desired_subset(3)
else:
    print('No such subset found that satisfies all constraints.')
```

Comment: it gets top 11 rows with max values but column a and b are all zeroes.  We need to find top rows but the column it should include should not zero @tlentali it gets top 11 rows with max values but column a and b are all zeroes.  We need to find top rows but the column it should include should not zero

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you mean that get 11 rows where at least there is one non zero element, moreover in this subset of 11 rows a column as a whole should not be zero. is this what you want?

Comment: Yes, with your solution it selects rows in such a way that in final outcome. Column a and b are completely zero. We need to get rows in such a way that at least 1 element in each column is 1 else can all be zero based on top values. 
So if top values return rows where 1 column is completely zero. we can swap it with another one but the non zero column constraint is must.

Comment: I think (df>1) this check should be at column level it's at the data frame level, so zero columns are accounted for as long as each row is non-zero.  But I am not sure

Comment: Edited, check it now.